# Deleting child records from Database when not present in entity with @OnetoMany in JPA/Hibernate (Spring boot application)

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm developing a Spring Boot web-application with JPA/Hibernate. The app receives the data records in JSON Format, which are mapped to @Entity classes. The Layout is rather simple, it has a main entity class with one set of child entities. I map these via @OneToMany/@ManytoOne. Parsing, reading data from DB, inserting/updating data in DB works all fine with the default repository-functions of JpaRepository....

The thing is, when I receive a record that has to be updated, I only want to store those child-records, that come with the request. If there are other child-records, which were stored earlier for the parent-record and which aren't present in the current record from the request, they have
to be deleted from the database.

My thoughts to achieve this is by comparing the set of child-records to the ones received from the Database, put those that were not present into a list and delete them, then persist the entity. An other option is to delete all child-records in the first place and then persisting the new entity....

My question now is: Isnt't there a more elegant way to achieve this with JPA/Hibernate. Some annotation or option or something. I didn't find any approach that worked for me yet. What are your ideas?

update:
my problem is not to delete the parent entity and then delete the child-records cascending. The parent entity stays as it is (or gets updated...). I want to only delete the child-records, and only those, which are not present in the current request entity but in database.

An example:
in the database in the parent-table is a record with parentID = 1. In the child-table are 3 referenced records stored with childIDs 1, 2, 3.

Now a client sends me an entity with parentID = 1 to update in database. In the child set there are only the child-entities with childID 1 and 2 present. Now the task is to update the entites (whatever in fields has changed) with having the child-record with id = 3 deleted from database

thanks and greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's cascading what you want to use. E.g. Cascase.REMOVE will automatically remove all child entities that are no longe referenced.

You can use it like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

A good overview can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-cascade-types

Comment: thanks for the reply. The thing is, the parent-record shall not get deleted... I'm looking for an approach to store the only the childs in database which are present in my current entity child-set. With Cascade.type remove i could delete the whole parent-record with all childs and then persist the whole entity again, but that seems to be an ugly method in my opinion

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, were you able to solve this issue with a more elegant solution than delete and then save again?